# How do I know if Nios II IORD is getting data from peripheral or cache?

Tags: nios-ii

For a Nios II system that has cache enabled, how do I know if the IORD is getting data from the actual peripheral or just reading the last value from cache?

As far as I know, cache conflicts of this nature can cause bugs that can be difficult to trace and reproduce.

Comment: You would normally have peripherals as non-cacheable as it makes no sense to cache something you know is very likely to change eg: uart status.

Comment: ok, and how is this achieved?

Comment: How is it achieved? By design. The mention of IORD suggests there is a peripheral address space - any access to that space should bypass the cache. For systems with a mmu and memory mapped peripherals, there is usually a tag bit in the map tables that specify a block of memory to be non-cacheable. I’ve had no direct exposure to NIOS, so I can’t give you a specific answer.